# Finding the volume of a 10-dimensional cube

Tags: intervals

I need help with finding the volume of a 10-dimensional cube with a given interval: $1 \geq x \geq -1$. I tried to defined the function by: $a^2+b^2+c^2...j^2 \leq 1$ as the question required. I can not find the codes that works for this problem. Does anyone know how to solve it by using the Monte Carlo method or any other method?

Comment: Isn't it just 2^10? Or was it supposed to be a hyper-dimensional ball?

Answer (score 4):

You can use region functionality for this. 10-dimensional hypercube (trivial):

```
RegionMeasure @ Cuboid[-ConstantArray[1, 10], ConstantArray[1, 10]]
```

> 1024

10-dimensional hyperball:

```
RegionMeasure @ Ball[ConstantArray[0, 10]]
```

> π^5/120